# Xcode 10 index problem, maybe caused by the new build system

Tags: indexing, xcode10

After upgrade to Xcode 10, when I open the project, or choose another file in editor, Xcode will cost a lot of time to index. I cannot jump to definition or other, action should dependency on the index. But I found that if change the build system to legacy, this problem can be solved. Is this the only way to solve this issue? Or there is a better way.

Comment: This problem would not be so serious in a little project. Our project has 1800+ swift files so the indexing problem is very...difficult to bear.

Answer (score 0):

I've restarted Xcode, loaded my workspace and then it worked.

Currently using legacy build settings, BTW.